# How to write unit test for loading handlebars template file in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, handlebars.js, jestjs

In my reactjs project, I am using handlebars to generate source code from the template. These templates are saved in files. In order to load these files into javascript, I configured below configuration in `webpack`:

```
{
        test: /\.handlebars|hbs$/,
        loader:
          'handlebars-loader?helperDirs[]=' +
            path.join(__dirname, '../src/helpers/handlebars')
      },
```

it works fine when I launch the production. But it doesn't work in my unit tests. I am using `jest` as unit test framework. I have seen some people suggest to use `Handlebars.registerHelper`. I know it works only for the template from `string`. How to solve the issue when I load the template from files?

Answer (score 5):

I created a preprocessor that simply put the handlebars template into a module so when imported in javascript via an es6 import, it can be used.

```
// preprocessor.js
module.exports = {
  process(src) {
    return `
    const Handlebars = require('handlebars');
    module.exports = \`${src}\`;
    `;
  },
};
```

Then in my package.json...

```
// package.json
"jest": {
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "modulePaths": [
      "./app",
      "./node_modules"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "/node_modules/",
      "/app/bower_components/"
    ],
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "hbs"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "\\.hbs$": "<rootDir>/app/scripts/preprocessor.js"
    }
  }
```

In a src file...

```
import Mn from 'backbone.marionette';
import template from './template.hbs';

const ToggleList = Mn.CompositeView.extend({
  template,
});

export default ToggleList;
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot but in my case I needed the unit test to compile the template too so I did it directly in the processor, instead of exporting the `src` variable I did something like this: `module.exports = Handlebars.compile(\`${src}\`);`

Comment: @ikertxu hey nice idea, thanks a lot for responding.

Comment: Can you clarify how you got this working? Both @ikertxu's and example still cause an error, unexpected token < .

Answer (score 3):

When loading handlebar templates while testing with Jest, I found that the [jest-handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-handlebars) package solved my problem.

From the docs:

> ```
> npm i jest-handlebars --save-dev
> ```
>
> To enable the processor please add the following rule to the transform
>   object in your jest configuration:
>
> ```
> "jest": {
>     // ...
>     transform: {
>         "\\.hbs$": "jest-handlebars",
>     }
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> Now all imported handlebars files will get compiled by the processor
>   and the render function is imported.